# Do we need to change Google Maps API key when changing computer?

Tags: android

The `Google Maps API` key is generated by `SHA1` from `keytool` on computer A.

Now i `checkout` the project on computer B (which means different `SHA1`).

Should i re-generate the key, or can i use the existing key?

Im not sure about this because my `BroadcastReceiver` suddenly not getting called when i `checkout` to computer B with same code.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same debug key across multiple machines by changing the signingConfig in your build.gradle.

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        storeFile file('..' + File.separator + 'debug.keystore')
        keyPassword "android"
        storePassword "android"
    }
}
```

This assumes that your debug keystore has been copied to the root of your project.

Comment: Should i copy the debug.keystore file manually to the root folder? And should i re-generate the API key after using this approach? Thanks a lot

Comment: Copying it manually should work fine. The API key only needs regenerating if you are using a different debug keystore from what you had before.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using the debug key, you will need to copy it to the new computer or use the new generated one, so you have to change the hash.

If you were using the release key you dont need to do anything more.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not setting a SHA1 when developing an app and keeping it blank. This would allow Google Maps to just work all of the time with that key. Then set one when signing your app before released, it would then be linked to your keystore.

Comment: What do you mean by keeping it blank? I cant generate any API key without SHA1. Thanks for your help

Comment: When generating your API key for maps in your Google Project console. You don't have to specify a SHA1, you can leave it blank.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new key for each computer.

I have a md file or text file for the project where I store my keys and depending on the computer, I just switch them out before building.